# Selecting unique rows in in groups with missing values

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I am having a table with two columns where the values of one of columns can be missing. First column is ID, second column is value.
 I wanna select rows for unique IDs such that if there is multiple rows with the same ID but some of them have missing value, then return one of those that have existing value. If all rows with the ID have empty value, then return any one of them.

In other words, As long as two rows have the same ID they should belong to same group. But within each group, return the one that has 'value' if there is such.

For example,
Input table.

```
+--------+---------+
|    ID  |  VALUE  |
+------------------+
| x      | 1       |
| x      | 1       |
| y      | 2       |
| y      |         |
| z      |         |
| z      |         |
+------------------+
```

Should return:

```
+------------+---------+
|    ID      |  VALUE  |
+------------+---------+
| x          | 1       |
| y          | 2       |
| z          |         |
+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you can just use `max()`:

```
select id, max(value)
from t
group by id;
```

If you have additional columns that you want, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (case when value is not null then 1 else 0 end)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This is good, although I would replace  `max(value)` with `arbitrary(value) filter(WHERE value IS NOT NULL)` -- more verbose, but more closer to the actual intent.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen . . . `arbitrary()` is quite specific to PrestoDB and not even available in Hive (the other tag).  `filter` is utterly unnecessary because `max()` ignores `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily divide your query in to two query:

```
A: 1- find unique row with DISTINCT on (ID,Value) which are not empty VALUE
B: 2- find unique row with DISTINCT on ID which are empty in VALUE and ID not in(A(ID))
```

A U (B - A)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **distinct function** in hive/sql

```
hive> select distinct id,value from <db_name>.<table_name>;
```

the above query will return distinct values in **id,value** columns

```
hive> select distinct * from <db_name>.<table_name>;
```

the above statement is used to return only distinct (different) values based on **all columns**.